# My website has font that is not supported/recognized in Firefox

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser

My website is not showing the appropriate font, PT Sans.ttc. I checked on other browsers and it works fine.

www.farmap-ux.com. Below is CSS code.

```
@font-face
{
font-family: PT Sans;
font-family: font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
src: url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans")
}
```

So it works on everything like I said (Chrome, Safari, even Opera!) Any ideas? I've tried to find .woff files for the font but I don't think it's in my Font Book.

Comment: Your site link doesn't seem to work... at least it doesn't for me.

Comment: Could it be that your CSS is invalid? It doesn't seem valid to me. First, you're using `PT Sans` without quotes, and then you're repeating `font-family: `. And you miss a semicolon at the end of the `src:` line.

Comment: Follow the directions at http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:PT+Sans to set up the font again on your website.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's because your `@font-face` declaration isn't valid at all. It should be something like:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('PT Sans'), local('PTSans-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ptsans/v4/LKf8nhXsWg5ybwEGXk8UBQ.woff) format('woff');
}
```

However, it's even better to use the CSS file provided by google:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans">
```

If you want to stick to a CSS import use

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans);
```

Comment: that didn't work either; you can preview this in firefox but it doesn't actually work in firefox

Answer (score 1):

You should really check your css! The syntaxe is miles away from correct.

Also, `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans` is already a css file!
what you should do is import is put it directly into the `<head>` your html using the `link` tag.

Have a look at this example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp, or just add the following to your html file as said before.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans">
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the directions at [Google Webfonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aPT+Sans) should fix your problem.

First, make sure you're including the Google CSS necessary to reference the font files. You have the option to include a `LINK` tag in your HTML, a `@import` directive in your CSS, or some Javascript. I recommend the `LINK` tag for maximum browser compatibility:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

When adding this CSS to your site, Google will automatically determine the correct font type to use for your browser. Not all browsers use WOFF files. Older versions of IE use EOT files, some browsers prefer SVG or TTF. Google is able to sniff for the browser type and modify the included CSS as necessary.

After Google's CSS is included, you only have to reference the font family in your CSS where you want the font to appear.

```
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
```

That's the only CSS necessary. Remove all the other CSS you linked… as mentioned in the other answers your CSS has some errors.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans");
}
```

Comment: The url isn't a valid font file but a `@font-face` declaration.

Comment: it works as a preview, but it doesn't work when actually being used on firefox for some reason. I don't understand why it does it like that.

Comment: Otherwise use the solution Zeta suggested: <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: when I say preview I mean I can view the local file when I edit it on Dreamweaver