# PT Sans rendering not correct on Mac

Tags: css

I'm using PT Sans as a webfont and I have the problem that the font is not displaying correctly on Chrome + Firefox on Mac.
On Chrome + Firefox on Windows its displaying correct.

There are little artifacts, I would say the font is fraying.
Ans the font is much bigger than on Windows, it seems to be 'bold' but it is 'normal'.

I tried it via Google Fonts and also via .ttf from Fontsquirrel.
But the problem is on both versions I tried.

Here my CSS-Code:

```
font-family: 'PT Sans';
```

Please help me, maybe someone had this problem too...
thx

Comment: Use a font stack, some browsers may not be able to render a certain fonts so you need a back up to serve up a similar font. Like this: `font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;` This will tell the browser that if it cannot load PT Sans, to load the next available sans-serif font.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247860/my-website-has-font-that-is-not-supported-recognized-in-firefox

Comment: Thanks, but I couldnt fix the problem.

Comment: My code is now exactly the code from the google fonts website. But the font is displaying incorrect.